# Filtering Text in a textbox using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to create a textbox which accepts text in english only and integers. Basically I would like to restrict the input in a textbox to be English only.

I guess it should be something using the keydown event. But how do I restrict the input box to accept A-Z a-z and 0-9 only?

Comment: When you say English, do you mean Latin text? What about characters that have accents?

Comment: Be careful - a naïve algorithm may exclude valid words.

Comment: @Duniyadnd - just need a-z A-Z and 0-9 thats all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would highly recommend [the masked input plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) for jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

HI,
      You can use regex(Regular Expresssion) to match the required criteria inyour case only english characters and digits.

Below is a sample that you can try to understand the working of regex for javascript.

> var myRegExp = /[a-zA-z]+/;
>
> var inputString = "www.dailycoding.com";
>
> var myMatches = document.frm1.txt1.value.match(myRegExp);
>
> for(var i=0; i
>
> {
>
> alert(myMatches[i]);
>
> }